# How to sum datagridview contents to database VB.net multiple users

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net

How can I sum the contents of my datagridview on my database. i have a code shown, however it just updates not sum.

So here is my code on save:

```
Public Sub save_dgv()
        Try
            con.Close()
            con.Open()
            Dim scb = New MySqlCommandBuilder(SDA)
            SDA.Update(dbDataset)
            MessageBox.Show("Submitted!")
            con.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub


sample:

user1
id--row1--row2--total
1 --25  -- 23 --48

user2
id--row1--row2--total
1 --25  -- 23 --48

output
id--row1--row2--total
1 --50-- 46--96
```

Comment: "what I want to happen is when user 1 submits, then user 2 submits, the values just ADD(+) not update. " Sounds like a **race condition**..

Comment: Could you clarify a little? Maybe show some sample output of what you would like to see happen? For some reason I read this 3-4 times and either your question is going right over my head or it's not worded well.

Comment: Edited.. should I use separate table for each  user? then add using sql?

Comment: a separate database table for each user? No. Don't even think about it. But anyway it's not clear what the issue really is - are you asking how to add new rows to your database? As haag1 says, please give a clear indication of the scenario - add some more code if necessary so we can understand what is happening with your gridview

Comment: I wanted to merge the input from user1 and user2 into 1 table. not change the values. :(

Comment: Maybe you should store them in separate rows of the same table, by _inserting_.  And then use a query to do the SUM operation when you want to view the result. The problem with your approach is that your code cannot know when another user has inserted the data before you, so you will keep over-writing the existing record. Collect all the input data as separate entries, and then use a query to add up the different values to get a total. That's a much more reliable design.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. Adjust data types to your db. Works in SQL Server but not tested in MySQL.

```
Using cn As New MySqlConnection("Your connection string")
            Dim s As String = "Update MyTable Set row1 = row1 + @row1, row2 = row2 + @row2 where id = @id"
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(s, cn)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@row1", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = intRow1
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@row2", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = intRow2
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = intID
                cn.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
End Using
```

Comment: I'll be trying this tonight. I will update you if successful! :D Thanks so much!